# Git rebase changes from parent branch not coming

Tags: git, git-rebase

I have 2 branches X and Y. X is parent of Y.

X have some feature-branches rebased into it for e.g X-F1, X-F2..

Y also have some feature-branches rebased into it.for e.g Y-F1, Y-F2..

All the feature-branches commits have been squashed on both X and Y branches

Now I want to rebase X onto Y

so i write command `git rebase X` while I am on branch Y

The issue is some changes from branch X are not coming after rebasing

I can see all the changes when I am on branch X but as you know after rebasing they are missing.

Comment: That command is backwards: `git rebase X` from Y should rebase Y onto X, not X onto Y.

Comment: More likely relevant: if the squashed Y-F1 commit introduces the same changes as the X-F1 commit already on X, the rebase will (or should) notice that and drop that commit, because it would be empty. Using `git rebase --empty ask X` to get prompted on what to do when rebase encounters this commit which is empty because the changes have already all been applied.

Comment: If actual changes to code is missing, please clarify the question.

Comment: One commit of X-F1 is missing after rebase

Comment: that commit is different from any other commit.

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: Note that in Git, *branches* do not have parents. *Commits* have parent/child relationships, but branch names simply select *one particular commit*. That's what leads to your problem here: never use squash merge for your setup. (For most users, this advice can be shortened to "don't use squash merges".)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now I want to rebase X onto Y
>
> so i write command `git rebase X` while I am on branch Y

That will rebase Y onto X.

---

Let's investigate:

> I have 2 branches X and Y. X is parent of Y.

Branches do not have parents, commits do. I assuming you meant "branch Y was branched off branch X at some point"

> X have some feature-branches rebased into it for e.g X-F1, X-F2..
>
> Y also have some feature-branches rebased into it.for e.g Y-F1, Y-F2..
>
> All the feature-branches commits have been squashed on both X and Y branches

According to your description, your history graph could look something like this:

```
x1-x2-xf1-x3-xf2-x4-x5        < X
           \
            y1-y2-yf1-y3-yf2  < Y
```

Now, running `git checkout Y && git rebase X` (which can be done with a single command: `git rebase X Y`), will produce the following history:

```
x1-x2-xf1-x3-xf2-x4-x5                       < X
                     \
                      y1'-y2'-yf1'-y3'-yf2'  < Y
```

But you claimed

> Now I want to rebase X onto Y

Which should be `git rebase Y X` (or the longer `git checkout X && git rebase Y`), resulting in the history:

```
x1-x2-xf1-x3                               < X
           \
            y1-y2-yf1-y3-yf2-xf2'-x4'-x5'  < Y
```

Rebase will automatically drop commits which it detects as being already applied or which would result in an empty change set.